# How to Interpolate Unknown Pixel given Coordinates references?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, interpolation

I just used Python for computer vision. I need lots of references for pixel interpolation in images using Python.

I have an RGB image like the following. In that picture, I have a white unknown pixel. I want to interpolate the unknown pixel starting from the point `(x0, y0)` using the colour intensity information along the blue line. Can someone provide code samples for interpolating at point `(x0, y0)` with any interpolation technique? The input is a collection of coordinate colour references `x,y = np.where(np.all(img == [0,0,255],axis=2))` and pixel coordinates `(x0, y0)`. The output is pixels `(x0, y0)` which have been interpolated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will solve ths problem using a bunch of functions.

First for a given coordinate `(x_i, y_i)`, I obtain the list of  pixel coordinates on both sides of it within a particular window of size = `window_size`

i.e

```
def derive_adjacent_coords(coord, window_size):
    # Coord is a tuple (row, column)

    assert (window_size % 2) != 0, "Window size must be odd"
    mid_idx = (window_size - 1) / 2)

    return [(r, coord[1]) for r in range(coord[0] - mid_idx, coord[0] + mid_idx + 1)]
```

Then I will I extract the values that correspond to these locations in the image using the function below:

```
def derive_adjacent_pixels(list_of_coord_tuples, image):
    # Image is your image, list_of_coord_tuples is the output of the first function
    return [ image[*i] for i in list_of_coord_tuples]
```

The function above will return a list.
Then I will interpolate the list:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import math

def interpol(list):
    # list is the output of the derive_adjacent_pixels(list_of_coord_tuples, image) function
    x = [i for i in range len(list)]
    interpolated_list = interp1d(x, list, kind='cubic')
    return interpolated_list[int(math.floor(len(interpolated_list)/2))]
```

You have to interpolate each band of the image differently in this method I have shown above.

You will have to iterate these functions over your list of unknown pixels coords (list of tuples) and then individually for each band in your image.